# set watchpoint on pthread's thread-local storage in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb, pthreads, thread-local-storage

Is it possible to set a watchpoint on pthread's thread-local storage using GDB? I have a program that runs:

```
struct stored_type *res = pthread_getspecific(tls_key);
```

...and after a few thousand calls it returns 0 instead of a valid pointer. I'd really love to figure out what's setting that value to 0. I've tried setting breakpoints on `pthread_setspecific` and `pthread_delete_key` (the only things I could think of that would reasonably cause the key to change value) and those breakpoints aren't getting hit, so I'm thinking there's some kind of overrun happening.

I'm using Linux x86_64 with glibc 2.23.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Exact details depend on the platform though, which you've kept secret. Is it Linux/x86_64/GLIBC, or something else?

Comment: I am indeed, and I've edited the question to include that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the only things I could think of that would reasonably cause the key to change value

The most likely reasons for `pthread_getspecific` to return `NULL`:

- you are in fact executing in a new thread, one in which `pthread_setspecific` hasn't been called,
- you are calling `pthread_getspecific` while current thread is in the process of being destroyed (i.e. `pthread_exit` is somewhere on the stack),
- you are calling `pthread_getspecific` in a signal handler (none of `pthread_*` functions are async-signal safe).

Assuming none of the above reasons are true in your case, on with the show.

First we need a test case to demonstrate on.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_key_t key;

void *thrfn(void *p) {
  int rc = pthread_setspecific(key, &p);
  assert(rc == 0);
  sleep(60);
  rc = pthread_setspecific(key, (void*)0x112233);
  assert(rc == 0);
  return p;
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thr;
  int rc = pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
  assert(rc == 0);

  rc = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thrfn, NULL);
  assert(rc == 0);

  sleep(90);
  return 0;
}

gcc -g -pthread t.c

gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) start
```

Now, it helps very much to have GLIBC that is compiled with debug info. Most distributions provide a `libc-dbg` or similar package, which supplies that. Looking at pthread_setspecific [source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_setspecific.c;h=965d463672bdd8e6d22db74c459cfb82ccf1267a;hb=HEAD#l25), you can see that inside the thread descriptor (`self`) there is a `specific_1stblock` array, where the space for first `PTHREAD_KEY_2NDLEVEL_SIZE` == 32 key slots is pre-allocated (32 distinct keys is usually more than enough).

The value that we pass will be stored in `self->specific_1stblock[key].data`, and that's exactly the location you'll want to set the watchpoint on.

In our sample program, `key == 0` (as this is the very first key). Putting it all together:

```
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:21
21        int rc = pthread_key_create(&key, NULL);
(gdb) b pthread_setspecific
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7bc9460: file pthread_setspecific.c, line 28.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[New Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 58683)]
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 58683)]

Breakpoint 2, __GI___pthread_setspecific (key=0, value=0x7ffff77f5ef8) at pthread_setspecific.c:28
28  pthread_setspecific.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) n
35  in pthread_setspecific.c
(gdb) n
28  in pthread_setspecific.c
(gdb) p self
$1 = (struct pthread *) 0x7ffff77f6700
(gdb) watch -l self.specific_1stblock[key].data
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location self.specific_1stblock[key].data
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location self.specific_1stblock[key].data

Old value = (void *) 0x0
New value = (void *) 0x7ffff77f5ef8
__GI___pthread_setspecific (key=<optimized out>, value=0x7ffff77f5ef8) at pthread_setspecific.c:89
89  in pthread_setspecific.c
```

Note that the new value is exactly the value that we passed to `pthread_setspecific`.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __GI___pthread_setspecific (key=0, value=0x112233) at pthread_setspecific.c:28
28  in pthread_setspecific.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location self.specific_1stblock[key].data

Old value = (void *) 0x7ffff77f5ef8
New value = (void *) 0x112233
__GI___pthread_setspecific (key=<optimized out>, value=0x112233) at pthread_setspecific.c:89
89  in pthread_setspecific.c
```

This is our second `pthread_setspecific` call

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware watchpoint 3: -location self.specific_1stblock[key].data

Old value = (void *) 0x112233
New value = (void *) 0x0
__nptl_deallocate_tsd () at pthread_create.c:152
152 pthread_create.c: No such file or directory.
```

And this is thread destruction, which deallocates the thread descriptor itself.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Thread 0x7ffff77f6700 (LWP 58683) exited]
[Inferior 1 (process 58677) exited normally]
```